# How to resolve NullReference Exception on String Array Objects?

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have a `String array` object in a class, i.e, `String[] particulars` which I want to initialize during runtime. The same code segment worked for another class object which was not array though.   Here `nd` is an object of class.

`int i=0;
    foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
           {
                nd.particulars[i] = row1["floor"].ToString();
                nd.quantity[i] = (double)row1["area"];
                nd.rate[i] = (double)row1["rate"];
                nd.amount[i] = (double)row1["amount"];
                i++;
           }`

The following code is throwing some `NullReferenceException`.  The error says:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

The class definition is as:

```
class NoteDetails
 {
    public string[] particulars;
    public double[] quantity;
    public double[] rate;
    public double[] amount;

    public string[] mparticulars;
    public double[] mquantity;
    public double[] mrate;
    public double[] mamount;

    public NoteDetails()
    {
        particulars = null;
        quantity = null;
        amount = null;
        rate = null;

        mparticulars = null;
        mquantity = null;
        mamount = null;
        mrate = null;
    }
 }
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created an Array for `nd.particulars` like so `nd.particulars = new String[size]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your string array (and your others arrays too). You can do that on the constructor of the class.

```
nd.particulars = new string[5]; //or whatever size
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the main issue that I ignored. :)

Answer (score 0):

*NullReferenceException** seems that one of your object is null ( nd or row1 or dt1 ). ***If something is null do not forget to instanciate it***.

You need to debug your code to check where you have this issue.

Furthermore, you should test if your object are null to avoid this error like this :

```
if( dt1 != null ){
 //do what you want
}
```

or like this (>= C#6 )

```
dt1?.Rows
```